# Azure Mobile Service/App Services On-Premises

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, mbaas

Microsoft Azure Mobile platform, Windows Azure Mobile Services WAMS, or its new version, App Services, are great Cloud and MBaaS tools for building mobile backends.  They use a NodeJS Restful Service Engine combined with an ORM Engine to provide a very easy-to-use platform.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use this framework outside the Azure Cloud environment, i.e. in an on-premises environment ?  Is this kind of NodeJS framework open ?  What is the name of this framework ?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Mobile Apps Node.js SDK to **Mobile Apps** is an express middleware package which makes it easy to create a backend for your mobile application.

The SDK package is still in development, but you can get all the code and documents at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node

About **Mobile Service in Node**, there is no full code project repository, but you can glance the entire code in KUDU console site of your mobile service, the URL should look like: `https://<your_mobile_service_name>.scm.azure-mobile.net/DebugConsole`. The root directory is `D:\home\site\wwwroot`

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Services and/or Azure Mobile Apps are only available in Azure. There is no 'framework' that you can download and install on your own infrastructures.

Besides the Node.Js version of Mobile Services there is also an .NET version which is basically just an MVC Web API with some additional 'services' added to it (notifications, authorization, etc.)

So, you could just build an MVC Web API app and manually add the missing components by using oAuth, entity framework, etc. However, this is probably not what you are looking for :)

Hope this helps!
Edward

Answer (score 0):

**Kudu** is the engine behind git/hg deployments, WebJobs, and various other features in Azure Web Sites. It can also run outside of Azure. It can run on premise https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu but unfortunately the rest of mobile services cannot